# What's wrong with the following get json function

Tags: python, json, api, url, get

I've tried this piece of code with a valid API key.

```
def get_json(url):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('Authorization', 'apikey token=' + API_KEY)]
    return json.loads(opener.open(url).read())
```

But got an error saying `"HTTP Error 414: Request-URI Too Large"` pointing at the return statement. Can anyone suggest what could have gone wrong. 
Thank you.

Comment: Show us the URL you are requesting. Also note that you should always `close()` open connections.

Comment: The URL I've requested is http://data.bioontology.org/annotator

Comment: No request parameters? Could you please edit the question adding the complete code you use to retrieve the JSON data?

Comment: Please find the edited code.

Comment: Since I have no API key, I cannot test it myself, please try [this code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1a9fec3065ba03e177cb). If it works, then it's an urllib2 bug (not likely, still a possibility), otherwise we have a probable application server programming error and you should get in touch with people running that service. I don't think that your current URL could be considered "too long" for any relevant definition of long. (edited gist code)

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: there is a [online form](http://bioportal.bioontology.org/annotator) that includes an API key. A binary search for the maximum reveals they'll accept a URL up to 30k characters, quite generous.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: what the OP isn't showing here is the *actual URL* they are using; in comments below they mention it is a 13KB file, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is raised by `opener.open()` because the HTTP server you tried to connect to returned a *414 Request-URI Too Large* response.

It means your URL (including the query parameters) is too long and the server refused to process it. In practice, *too long* is usually reached when you send more than 2000 characters in the URL, but it depends on the server, really.

You need to use a shorter URL; perhaps you are trying to put too many elements into query parameters. The specific API you are calling takes slightly less than 30k characters, max. for the whole URL (28820 to be exact).

It depends entirely on what API you are trying to call what your options are here. Perhaps the server also supports sending a POST request with the query parameters sent as a request body instead of in the query string, for example.

Comment: Is there a way I can fix it?

Comment: @user3783999: use a shorter URL. Without any details of what you are doing, I cannot help you any more than give you that advice.

Comment: I edited the question adding more details. Thank you.

Comment: @user3783999: you didn't show us where you build `url` though.

Comment: @user3783999: how are you calling `get_json()` in your code? What is the value of the parameter you are using *there*?

Comment: @user3783999: so, *how large is your text*?

Comment: @user3783999: there's your problem. 13000 characters > 2000 characters.

Comment: Can I not use it for >2000 characters, ever?

Comment: @user3783999: it depends on the server; I just tested it and they accept 30000 characters (for the *whole* URL).

Comment: @user3783999: so presumably the 13KB file you have is compressed, as that'd be less than 30000 characters if it wasn't.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on the whole URL. Thank you.

Comment: It has 12,231 characters including spaces.

Comment: @user3783999: The whole url including the `http://data.bioontology.org/annotator` part plus the `?` query string delimiter, the `text=` name, any url encoding, any other parameters. The total length of the `url` value passed to `getjson()`.

Comment: @user3783999: You'll have to ask the maintainers of the service; it could be that the API key I got from the [online form](http://bioportal.bioontology.org/annotator) has different limits applied than your own. I certainly cannot help you more than I already have here, really.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to fix it. Thank you very much for the help